# Error creating EntityManagerFactory when trying to access H2 embedded in-memory database through Hibernate in WebSphere

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-ee-6, h2, websphere-8

When trying to use H2 embedded in-memory database in WebSphere I'm getting the following error:

```
EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : 
PuId=javaee6-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war#javaee6-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#javaee6
```

`javaee6` is the name of my application, which I build to `javaee6-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` using Maven.

My attempt to deploy H2 on WebSphere was by coping `h2-1.3.173.jar` to `WebSphere\AppServer8\lib` and restarting the server.

My WebSphere version is 8.0.0.5.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="javaee6" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.learning.business.car.Car</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Managed bean:

```
package com.learning.app.car;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import com.learning.business.car.CarRepo;

@ManagedBean
public class CarBean {

    @EJB
    public CarRepo carRepo;

    public Integer getCarsCount() {
        return carRepo.getAll().size();
    }
}
```

EJB module:

```
package com.learning.business.car;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

@Stateless
public class CarRepo {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<Car> getAll() {

        TypedQuery<Car> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Car c", Car.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
package com.learning.business.car;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

cars.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
    <body>
        <h:outputText value="I have #{carBean.carsCount}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The complete stack trace error shown when I access the page:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=javaee6-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war#javaee6-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#javaee6
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=javaee6-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war#javaee6-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#javaee6
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=javaee6-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war#javaee6-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#javaee6
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1425)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerPool(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1652)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.<init>(JPATxEntityManager.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.AbstractJPAComponent.getEntityManager(AbstractJPAComponent.java:509)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.getEntityManager(JPAComponentImpl.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.java:176)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1003)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:924)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1358)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate(UncachedActivationStrategy.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.preInvokeActivateBean(Activator.java:614)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:4110)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3476)
    at com.learning.business.car.EJSLocalNSLCarRepo_a1ab5865.getAll(EJSLocalNSLCarRepo_a1ab5865.java)
    at com.learning.business.car.CarBean.getCarsCount(CarBean.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:91)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:343)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:295)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderOutput(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:92)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:79)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:535)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1320)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere includes an OpenJPA implementation and uses it by default. If you want to use third party make sure you configure it correctly either in application or via shared library. Check these links how to configure third party JPA and Hibernate:

- [AlternateJPAProviders_TestReport](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/form/anonymous/api/library/53181ccd-bcd4-431f-b968-0b5f6d46d652/document/192a432b-28bb-4080-b037-345e5d83da76/attachment/61e74f67-1d60-4120-ba25-ad7264c9f4f6/media/AlternateJPAProviders_TestReport.pdf)
- [Using third-party persistence providers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.0.0%2F2-3-6-2-2-0-0-3-0-0&lang=en)

And avoid putting jar files to the `WebSphere\AppServer8\lib`. If you are packing JPA provider with your application try to put h2-1.3.173.jar there also (WEB-INF/lib). Or create JDBC Provider and DataSource, and use Datasource in your persistence.xml.

If you want to use default provider:

- Remove `<provider>` element to use default, and remove Hibernate JPA jars from application:

> `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`

- Replace hibernate related properties with default JPA
  either using DataSource:

> `<jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSourceJNDI</jta-data-source>`

or using connection properties:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
```

For more details how to configure default provider see this page: [Associating persistence providers and data sources](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/tejb_defjpadatasource.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5%2F1-3-6-2-1-0-3&lang=en)

Comment: So how should I configure my persistence.xml to use WebSphere JPA provider?

Comment: @Caffé Updated answer with some more info.

Comment: It seems to be solving my problem. Thanks! But I was using a Hibernate property to auto create my DB schema (`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />`). How can I keep this behaviour without Hibernate?

Comment: WebSphere uses openJPA, try the following property <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>, it may need some other configuration as well

Comment: Yeah, I've just found it :-)

Comment: And would you know how to do it work using embeddable container while JUnit testing? See my new question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651413/entitymanager-not-being-injected-in-ejb-module-instantiated-by-websphere-embedda